# AWS iot with esp8266

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, iot, esp8266, arduino-ide

Please help me connect with AWS IOT services with esp8266 12e.
I am using aws-mqtt-websocket example but I an not able to connect with AWS IOT. 
The code is as follows and the error I get is: `please start sntp first ! error connection to the websocket server`.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Stream.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

//AWS
#include "sha256.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include "AWSClient2.h"

//WEBSockets
#include <Hash.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>

//MQTT PAHO
#include <SPI.h>
#include <IPStack.h>
#include <Countdown.h>
#include <MQTTClient.h>

//AWS MQTT Websocket
#include "Client.h"
#include "AWSWebSocketClient.h"
#include "CircularByteBuffer.h"

//AWS IOT config, change these:

const char* ssid = "XXXX";
const char* password = "XXXXXXXX";
char aws_endpoint[] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
char aws_key[] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
char aws_secret[] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
char aws_region[] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const char* aws_topic = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
int port = 443;

//MQTT config
const int maxMQTTpackageSize = 512;
const int maxMQTTMessageHandlers = 1;

WiFiClientSecure espclient;

AWSWebSocketClient awsWSclient(1000);

IPStack ipstack(awsWSclient);

MQTT::Client<IPStack, Countdown, maxMQTTpackageSize, maxMQTTMessageHandlers> *client = NULL;

//# of connections
long connection = 0;

//generate random mqtt clientID
char* generateClientID() {
    char* cID = new char[23]();
    for (int i = 0; i<22; i += 1)
        cID[i] = (char)random(1, 256);
    return cID;
}

//count messages arrived
int arrivedcount = 0;


//callback to handle mqtt messages
void messageArrived(MQTT::MessageData& md)
{
    MQTT::Message &message = md.message;

    Serial.print("Message ");
    Serial.print(++arrivedcount);
    Serial.print(" arrived: qos ");
    Serial.print(message.qos);
    Serial.print(", retained ");
    Serial.print(message.retained);
    Serial.print(", dup ");
    Serial.print(message.dup);
    Serial.print(", packetid ");
    Serial.println(message.id);
    Serial.print("Payload ");
    char* msg = new char[message.payloadlen + 1]();
    memcpy(msg, message.payload, message.payloadlen);
    Serial.println(msg);
    delete msg;
}

//connects to websocket layer and mqtt layer
bool connect() {

    if (client == NULL) {
        client = new MQTT::Client<IPStack, Countdown, maxMQTTpackageSize, maxMQTTMessageHandlers>(ipstack);
    }
    else {

        if (client->isConnected()) {
            client->disconnect();
        }
        delete client;
        client = new MQTT::Client<IPStack, Countdown, maxMQTTpackageSize, maxMQTTMessageHandlers>(ipstack);
    }


    //delay is not necessary... it just help us to get a "trustful" heap space value
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(millis());
    Serial.print(" - conn: ");
    Serial.print(++connection);
    Serial.print(" - (");
    Serial.print(ESP.getFreeHeap());
    Serial.println(")");




    int rc = ipstack.connect(aws_endpoint, port);
    Serial.print(rc);

    if (rc != 1)
    {
        Serial.println("error connection to the websocket server");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("websocket layer connected");
    }


    Serial.println("MQTT connecting");
    MQTTPacket_connectData data = MQTTPacket_connectData_initializer;
    data.MQTTVersion = 3;
    char* clientID = generateClientID();
    data.clientID.cstring = clientID;
    rc = client->connect(data);
    delete[] clientID;
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        Serial.print("error connection to MQTT server");
        Serial.println(rc);
        return false;
    }
    Serial.println("MQTT connected");
    return true;
}

//subscribe to a mqtt topic
void subscribe() {
    //subscript to a topic
    int rc = client->subscribe(aws_topic, MQTT::QOS0, messageArrived);
    Serial.println(rc);
    if (rc != 0) {
        Serial.print("rc from MQTT subscribe is ");
        Serial.println(rc);
        return;
    }
    Serial.println("MQTT subscribed");
}

//send a message to a mqtt topic
void sendmessage() {
    //send a message
    MQTT::Message message;
    char buf[100];
    strcpy(buf, "{\"state\":{\"reported\":{\"on\": false}, \"desired\":{\"on\": false}}}");
    message.qos = MQTT::QOS0;
    message.retained = false;
    message.dup = false;
    message.payload = (void*)buf;
    message.payloadlen = strlen(buf) + 1;
    int rc = client->publish(aws_topic, message);
}

void setup_wifi() {

    delay(10);
    // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    setup_wifi();

    Serial.setDebugOutput(1);
    //fill AWS parameters    
    awsWSclient.setAWSRegion(aws_region);
    awsWSclient.setAWSDomain(aws_endpoint);
    awsWSclient.setAWSKeyID(aws_key);
    awsWSclient.setAWSSecretKey(aws_secret);
    awsWSclient.setUseSSL(true);

    if (connect()) {
        subscribe();
        sendmessage();
    }
}

void loop() {
    //keep the mqtt up and running
    if (awsWSclient.connected()) {
        client->yield();
    }
    else {
        //handle reconnection
        if (connect()) {
            subscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Include details about your IAM Rule and AWS-IoT Policy

Answer (score 4):

You need to attach *AWSIoTFullAccess* policy to unauthenticated role in IAM.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post describing how to connect an ESP32 to AWS IoT covering all the steps you have to follow. You can find the source code too.
Maybe it could help you.
Give a look at https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/how-to-connect-esp32-to-aws-iot-core-using-aws-mqtt/

Let me know if it is useful for you

Answer (score 0):

First of all give us some more details about what you did so far.

Did you installed all the required libraries that are mentioned in the tutorial correctly?
Also,as the others are saying, did you attached an AWSIoTFullAccess policy? Also has the IAM user you are mentioning the required permissions?